# Padronizar número de telefone com REGEX no R

Tags: r, string, regex

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Estou tentando padronizar a coluna "numero_telefonico" deste dataset: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rivaquiroga/latinr-taller-regex/master/datos/telefonos.csv

Baixo o dataset e gravo em um objeto **telefonos**

```
telefonos<- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rivaquiroga/latinr-taller-regex/master/datos/telefonos.csv")

telefonos

> telefonos
# A tibble: 19 x 3
   nombre               ciudad     numero_telefonico
   <chr>                <chr>      <chr>            
 1 Pérez, María         Valparaíso +56 981497134    
 2 Juan González        Olmué      928374591        
 3 Hernández, Lautaro   quilpué    56 964379583     
 4 Lobos, Antonia       La Serena  987654321        
 5 Martínez, José       La Serena  +56-983726153    
 6 Manuel Garrido       valparaiso 914230795        
 7 Soto, Loreto         valparaíso 925479238        
 8 Pérez, Pedro         valparaíso 985740293        
 9 González, Camila     Valparaiso 56 973629584     
10 Jiménez, Luis        Olmué      925403948        
11 Sanhueza, Pedro      quilpué    56 981408973     
12 Aníbal García        quilpue    982733747        
13 Gómez, Lirayén       quilpué    914257483        
14 Cayuqueo, Marina     Valparaíso 973629853        
15 Jaime Espinoza       Valparaíso 56981359284      
16 Hernández, Francisca Valparaíso 56993418209      
17 López, Carla         Serena     56912338475      
18 Soto, Martina        Serena     925653948        
19 González, Olivia     Valparaíso no tengo
```

No fim das contas, consegui meu objetivo usando `str_sub()`:

```
telefonos %>% 
  mutate(numero = str_sub(numero_telefonico, start = -9, end = -1),
         cod = 56)

# A tibble: 19 x 5
   nombre               ciudad     numero_telefonico numero      cod
   <chr>                <chr>      <chr>             <chr>     <dbl>
 1 Pérez, María         Valparaíso +56 981497134     981497134    56
 2 Juan González        Olmué      928374591         928374591    56
 3 Hernández, Lautaro   quilpué    56 964379583      964379583    56
 4 Lobos, Antonia       La Serena  987654321         987654321    56
 5 Martínez, José       La Serena  +56-983726153     983726153    56
 6 Manuel Garrido       valparaiso 914230795         914230795    56
 7 Soto, Loreto         valparaíso 925479238         925479238    56
 8 Pérez, Pedro         valparaíso 985740293         985740293    56
 9 González, Camila     Valparaiso 56 973629584      973629584    56
10 Jiménez, Luis        Olmué      925403948         925403948    56
11 Sanhueza, Pedro      quilpué    56 981408973      981408973    56
12 Aníbal García        quilpue    982733747         982733747    56
13 Gómez, Lirayén       quilpué    914257483         914257483    56
14 Cayuqueo, Marina     Valparaíso 973629853         973629853    56
15 Jaime Espinoza       Valparaíso 56981359284       981359284    56
16 Hernández, Francisca Valparaíso 56993418209       993418209    56
17 López, Carla         Serena     56912338475       912338475    56
18 Soto, Martina        Serena     925653948         925653948    56
19 González, Olivia     Valparaíso no tengo          no tengo     56
```

No entanto, queria fazer essa operação usando REGEX.

Eu tentei o seguinte: criei uma outra coluna chamada **"numero_telefonico_2"**, usando `str_replace_all()` para  eliminar os sinais ("+" e '-') e os whitespaces.
Gravei no objeto "telefonos_2"

```
telefonos_2<-telefonos %>% 
  mutate(numero_telefonico_2 = str_replace_all(numero_telefonico, "[\\+, \\-]", ""))

telefonos_2

# A tibble: 19 x 4
   nombre               ciudad     numero_telefonico numero_telefonico_2
   <chr>                <chr>      <chr>             <chr>              
 1 Pérez, María         Valparaíso +56 981497134     56981497134        
 2 Juan González        Olmué      928374591         928374591          
 3 Hernández, Lautaro   quilpué    56 964379583      56964379583        
 4 Lobos, Antonia       La Serena  987654321         987654321          
 5 Martínez, José       La Serena  +56-983726153     56983726153        
 6 Manuel Garrido       valparaiso 914230795         914230795          
 7 Soto, Loreto         valparaíso 925479238         925479238          
 8 Pérez, Pedro         valparaíso 985740293         985740293          
 9 González, Camila     Valparaiso 56 973629584      56973629584        
10 Jiménez, Luis        Olmué      925403948         925403948          
11 Sanhueza, Pedro      quilpué    56 981408973      56981408973        
12 Aníbal García        quilpue    982733747         982733747          
13 Gómez, Lirayén       quilpué    914257483         914257483          
14 Cayuqueo, Marina     Valparaíso 973629853         973629853          
15 Jaime Espinoza       Valparaíso 56981359284       56981359284        
16 Hernández, Francisca Valparaíso 56993418209       56993418209        
17 López, Carla         Serena     56912338475       56912338475        
18 Soto, Martina        Serena     925653948         925653948          
19 González, Olivia     Valparaíso no tengo          notengo
```

A partir daqui, pensei em usar o `separate()` para dividir tudo o que vem antes do primeiro "9" (que se refere ao código do país), no entanto não estou sabendo que argumento devo passar para o parametro `sep =`
Se coloco o "9", fica uma bagunça

```
telefonos_2 %>% 
    separate(numero_telefonico_2,
             into = c("codigo","numero"),
             sep = "9")

# A tibble: 19 x 5
   nombre               ciudad     numero_telefonico codigo    numero    
   <chr>                <chr>      <chr>             <chr>     <chr>     
 1 Pérez, María         Valparaíso +56 981497134     "56"      "814"     
 2 Juan González        Olmué      928374591         ""        "283745"  
 3 Hernández, Lautaro   quilpué    56 964379583      "56"      "6437"    
 4 Lobos, Antonia       La Serena  987654321         ""        "87654321"
 5 Martínez, José       La Serena  +56-983726153     "56"      "83726153"
 6 Manuel Garrido       valparaiso 914230795         ""        "142307"  
 7 Soto, Loreto         valparaíso 925479238         ""        "2547"    
 8 Pérez, Pedro         valparaíso 985740293         ""        "857402"  
 9 González, Camila     Valparaiso 56 973629584      "56"      "7362"    
10 Jiménez, Luis        Olmué      925403948         ""        "25403"   
11 Sanhueza, Pedro      quilpué    56 981408973      "56"      "81408"   
12 Aníbal García        quilpue    982733747         ""        "82733747"
13 Gómez, Lirayén       quilpué    914257483         ""        "14257483"
14 Cayuqueo, Marina     Valparaíso 973629853         ""        "7362"    
15 Jaime Espinoza       Valparaíso 56981359284       "56"      "8135"    
16 Hernández, Francisca Valparaíso 56993418209       "56"      ""        
17 López, Carla         Serena     56912338475       "56"      "12338475"
18 Soto, Martina        Serena     925653948         ""        "25653"   
19 González, Olivia     Valparaíso no tengo          "notengo"  NA       
Warning messages:
1: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 13 rows [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18]. 
2: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [19].
```

Tentei também `str_split()` mas também não estou acertando no delimitador da separação (o primeiro "9")

```
split_numero_telefonico_2<-str_split(telefonos_2$numero_telefonico_2, "[9]", simplify = T)

split_numero_telefonico_2

      [,1]      [,2]       [,3]     [,4]
 [1,] "56"      "814"      "7134"   ""  
 [2,] ""        "283745"   "1"      ""  
 [3,] "56"      "6437"     "583"    ""  
 [4,] ""        "87654321" ""       ""  
 [5,] "56"      "83726153" ""       ""  
 [6,] ""        "142307"   "5"      ""  
 [7,] ""        "2547"     "238"    ""  
 [8,] ""        "857402"   "3"      ""  
 [9,] "56"      "7362"     "584"    ""  
[10,] ""        "25403"    "48"     ""  
[11,] "56"      "81408"    "73"     ""  
[12,] ""        "82733747" ""       ""  
[13,] ""        "14257483" ""       ""  
[14,] ""        "7362"     "853"    ""  
[15,] "56"      "8135"     "284"    ""  
[16,] "56"      ""         "341820" ""  
[17,] "56"      "12338475" ""       ""  
[18,] ""        "25653"    "48"     ""  
[19,] "notengo" ""         ""       ""
```

E uma segunda dúvida: Qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com o registro "no tengo"?
Nesse exemplo, ele só aparece uma vez, então fica fácil checar. Mas fiquei me perguntando: e se o dataset fosse gigante, com o risco de outros registros digitados de diversas formas ("no teng", "notengo", etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver esse problema com uma expressão regular, eu usaria a expressão `.*(?=.{9}$)`, que vai extrair os 9 últimos caracteres de cada campo dentro de `numero_telefonico`. Como há uma ocorrência igual a `no tengo`, a coluna `numero_telefonico_2` resultante será do tipo `chr`.

Vou aproveitar que o `R` converte caracteres do tipo `"324"` no número adequado (isso é, em `324` nesse caso) e converter toda a coluna `numero_telefonico_2` em numérico. Assim, tudo que o `R` encontrar que não tenha uma relação direta com um número (ou seja, quaisquer strings como `"no teng"`, `"notengo"` etc) serão codificadas como `NA`. Assim, um simples `na.omit` removeria as linhas do objeto `telefonos` que não possuem números telefônicos, caso isso seja necessário.

Fiz isso em duas etapas abaixo por motivos didáticos. É um pouco mais verboso, mas acho que fica mais claro assim.

```r
telefonos %>%
  mutate(numero_telefonico_2 = sub(".*(?=.{9}$)", "", numero_telefonico, perl = T)) %>%
  mutate(numero_telefonico_2 = as.numeric(numero_telefonico_2))
#> Warning: Problem with `mutate()` input `numero_telefonico_2`.
#> ℹ NAs introduced by coercion
#> ℹ Input `numero_telefonico_2` is `as.numeric(numero_telefonico_2)`.
#> Warning in mask$eval_all_mutate(dots[[i]]): NAs introduced by coercion
#> # A tibble: 19 x 4
#>    nombre               ciudad     numero_telefonico numero_telefonico_2
#>    <chr>                <chr>      <chr>                           <dbl>
#>  1 Pérez, María         Valparaíso +56 981497134               981497134
#>  2 Juan González        Olmué      928374591                   928374591
#>  3 Hernández, Lautaro   quilpué    56 964379583                964379583
#>  4 Lobos, Antonia       La Serena  987654321                   987654321
#>  5 Martínez, José       La Serena  +56-983726153               983726153
#>  6 Manuel Garrido       valparaiso 914230795                   914230795
#>  7 Soto, Loreto         valparaíso 925479238                   925479238
#>  8 Pérez, Pedro         valparaíso 985740293                   985740293
#>  9 González, Camila     Valparaiso 56 973629584                973629584
#> 10 Jiménez, Luis        Olmué      925403948                   925403948
#> 11 Sanhueza, Pedro      quilpué    56 981408973                981408973
#> 12 Aníbal García        quilpue    982733747                   982733747
#> 13 Gómez, Lirayén       quilpué    914257483                   914257483
#> 14 Cayuqueo, Marina     Valparaíso 973629853                   973629853
#> 15 Jaime Espinoza       Valparaíso 56981359284                 981359284
#> 16 Hernández, Francisca Valparaíso 56993418209                 993418209
#> 17 López, Carla         Serena     56912338475                 912338475
#> 18 Soto, Martina        Serena     925653948                   925653948
#> 19 González, Olivia     Valparaíso no tengo                           NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Olá Marcus, grato pela retorno.
Funcionou! No entanto, queria saber se seria possível "traduzir" a REGEX?

Até onde consegui entender, é o seguinte:
```.*``` [Tudo que venha de acordo como especificado dentro dos parenteses]

O que esta dentro dos parenteses significa:
  
```?=``` [que seja seguido por...]

Pronto, daí pra frente, me perdi.
Interpretei que ```.{9}$``` seria os últimos 9 dígitos a contar de trás (já que o "$" ancora ao final da string)
Mas, não é isso, pois uso o ```str_extract()``` e a função retorna o que não é o conjunto de 9 dígitos.